# IF and Arrayformula for Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

`=IF(C2=""(vlookup('FBA Returns'!B:J,9,0),vlookup(C2:C'RMA Main Sheet'!D2:H,5,0)))`

IF "C" is blank, Vlookup "B" on Sheet 1, IF "C" is NOT Blank Vlookup Sheet 2.

Also, turn this to Arrayformula and skip the return value row is NOT BLANK.

Please advise.

Comment: Hi welcome to WebApps. let's start with an error in your formula. I think this is probably what you intended: `=IF(C2="",vlookup(B2,'FBA Returns'!B:J,9,0),vlookup(B2,'RMA Main Sheet'!D2:H,5,0))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Sheets, using VLOOKUP and ARRAYFORMULA to search multi-line cells](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/154537/google-sheets-using-vlookup-and-arrayformula-to-search-multi-line-cells)